# Julia - Sort a dict that contains elements of Dict

Tags: dictionary, julia

Suppose I have a global dict `parent` that contains some `child` like

```
parent = Dict( child1, child2, ...);
```

And each `child` is another dict of

```
child = Dict("weight" => 100.0; "height" = 10.0);
```

Is there a way to sort these childs in the parent respect to some category? Like I want to product a `parent` which has the child nodes sorted according to their `weight`?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more precise? What are the keys for the `parent` dictionary?

Comment: I initilise my `parent` with `parent = Dict[];` and then after each iteration, I simply push `push!(parent, child);`.

Comment: Thanks. So `parent` is a `Vector{Dict{K,V}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,

```
sort!(parent,by=x->x["weight"])
```

should do the trick. Use `sort` (no `!`) to return a new vector. Try `?sort` in REPL for more options.